# Docker can create a new swarm

Tags: docker, swarm

**I am using the docker docs to create a swarm**

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/create-swarm/

[centos@dsm-manager1 ~]$ docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.192.10.220

Error response from daemon: --live-restore daemon configuration is incompatible with swarm mode
[centos@dsm-manager1 ~]$

**The version of docker I'm using**

[centos@dsm-manager1 ~]$ docker version

Client:
 Version:         1.12.6

API version:     1.24

Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-11.el7.centos.x86_64

Go version:      go1.7.4

Git commit:      96d83a5/1.12.6

Built:           Tue Mar  7 09:23:34 2017

OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:

Version:         1.12.6

API version:     1.24

Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-11.el7.centos.x86_64

Go version:      go1.7.4

Git commit:      96d83a5/1.12.6

Built:           Tue Mar  7 09:23:34 2017

OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

**The doc version is 1.17,I don't know whether this matters,
I just can't find the doc about swarm mode in version 1.12**

Comment: A lot has changed around docker swarm in the last releases. I would try again with the current docker version

Comment: Thank you all the same,I've changed the value of live-store in /etc/docker/daemon.json from true to false,and it works!

Answer (score 4):

For those who can’t find `/etc/docker/daemon.json` try `/etc/sysconfig/docker`

live-restore option is there:

```
OPTIONS=’–selinux-enabled --log-driver=journald --live-restore’
```